# How do you store data in the memory without using a variable within Assembly (NASM)?

Tags: memory-management, assembly, nasm

I have search every webpage for an answer but I cant seem to find it. I have been learning the net-wide assembly syntax for around 2 months, and I'm trying to find a way to store data in the memory.

I know that sys_break:

```
    mov,eax 45
```

reserves memory, and I have a functional macro which reserves 16kb of memory:

```
    %macro reserve_mem
    mov eax,45
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 80h
    add eax,16384
    mov ebx,eax
    mov eax,45
    int 80h
    %endmacro
```

I also know that when you reserve bytes (resb), words ect. in the .bss section, small parts of memory are allocated to that uninitialised data.

In addition, there is virtual memory which can be accessed with an address like 0x0000, and this is then mapped into its actual memory location.

However, my problem is that I am trying to store data in the memory, but everything I try ends in a segmentation fault(core dumped) which is the programm trying to access memory it doesn't have access to. I have tried code such as below.

```
     mov [0x0000],eax
```

Thankyou for the help.

Comment: Why `0x0000`? You should only access memory that has been allocated to your process, either statically with `resb` et al, or dynamically with e.g. `sys_brk`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however is it possible to do so, such as putting the number 1 into the memory?

Comment: @morgan At least x86 supports such a operation.  Are you familiar with C or other programming languages?  What kind of experience do you have in the field of computer programming?  We need to know your level in order to give an effective advice to you.

Comment: Which memory do you want to write to? The block you allocated with `sys_brk`? You can't just write to random addresses.

Comment: nodakai, i am 15 and have knowledge in java and a little C, and Michael, yes i would like to write to the memory i have allocated, if that is possible. Thanks for helping.

Comment: After the memory allocation (i.e. after the last instruction of your `reserve_mem` macro), `eax` will contain the new highest available address. If you subtract the size of the block you allocated (16384) from that you get the starting address of the allocated block. You should be able to write to any byte in the range starting_address..starting_address+16383.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the concept of virtual memory.  It's similar to telephone number in that you cannot call someone at every combination of some 10 digits.  You are supopsed to call at only those numbers listed in the telephone book.  Otherwise you'll hear "Sorry, this number is currently out of service".  Likewise, only those virtual addresses listed in the page table of each process (always automatically and transparently maintained by OS) are valid for the process to access.  SEGV is OS's way of saying "Sorry, this virtual address is currently out of service."

In your code, you dereferenced `0x0000` but it is one of the least possible values for a vaild virtual address.  You ended up in doing so because you had thrown away the valid virtual address returned by the `brk(2)` syscall (read `man 2 brk` carefully because the raw syscall behaves diffrently from both of glibc `brk` and `sbrk`.)  Your code would translate to C in this way (though nowadays glibc `malloc(3)` often relies on `mmap(2)` rather than `brk(2)`):

```
void *p = malloc(16384);
int eax = ...;
(void *)0 = eax;
```

This is obviously wrong and you must do something like this:

```
void *p = malloc(16384);
int *p0 = (int *)p + 0;
int *p1 = (int *)p + 1;
int eax = ...;
int ebx = ...; /* it's all up to you which register to use */
*p0 = eax;
*p1 = ebx;
```

which should translates to NASM like this:

```
reserve_mem  ; IIRC eax now points to the last
mov ecx, eax ; byte of the newly allocated chunk
sub ecx, 16383 ; set p0 (== p)
mov edx, ecx
add edx, 4 ; set p1; 4 is for sizeof(int)
; ... set whatever value to eax ...
; ... set whatever value to ebx ...
mov [ecx], eax ; *p0 = eax;
mov [edx], ebx ; *p1 = ebx;
```

My knowledge on assembly programming is rusting and the above codes may contain many errors...  but the concept part should not be so wrong.

Comment: Thanks, you and michael have extended my knowledge so that i can start to try and develop more sophisticated programmes.